# How find record with conditions for joined associations

Tags: sql, ruby-on-rails, rails-activerecord

I have:

`RevieweeCycle` belongs_to `ReviewCycle`, `ReviewCycle` has_many `Reviews` (through other model), `Review` has one of statuses: *created*, *saved*, etc. `RevieweeCycle` is completed when all reviews of his `ReviewCycle` has one of statuses - *completed* or *approved*. I want to find last completed `RevieweeCycle`.

How I can find it with one query? 
Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
ReviewCycle.where(review_id: Review.where("status is ?", ["completed", "approved"])).revieweecycles.order("updated_at DESC")
```

Comment: The user asked one query. Your code is triggering two queries.

Comment: @SimoneCarletti No the user wants last completed revieweecycles so we need to get revieweecycles through reviewcycle through reviews

Answer (score 0):

Use the SQL JOIN syntax.

```
ReviewCycle.joins(:reviews).where(reviews: { status: %w( completed approved ) }).order(updated_at: :desc).first
```

This is a shorter version for

```
ReviewCycle.joins(:reviews).where(reviews: { status: ["completed", "approved"] }).order(updated_at: :desc).first
```

or

```
ReviewCycle.joins(:reviews).where("reviews.status IN (?)", ["completed", "approved"]).order(updated_at: :desc).first
```

Comment: If I'll use your version then some of results don't suit to me, as example ReviewCycle that has one review with status 'completed' and one with 'incompleted'. But I want ReviewCycles where all reviews are completed